# Async Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture in .net-4.6

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, cultureinfo, .net-4.6

Because of the following information from microsoft, I updated my code a bit. It sounds like they updated the currentculture to something I could use.

> For apps that target the .NET Framework 4.6 and later versions,
>   CultureInfo.CurrentCulture and CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture are stored
>   in a thread's ExecutionContext, which flows across asynchronous
>   operations.
>   (source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn833123(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("start " + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        RunAsync().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Finish " + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");

        Console.WriteLine("1 " + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        string cultureInTask = string.Empty;

        await Task.Run(() => cultureInTask = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId).ConfigureAwait(true);

        Console.WriteLine("2 " + cultureInTask);
        string twoA = await TestMethodAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("2a " + twoA + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine("3 " + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);            
    }

    public static async Task<string> TestMethodAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("2s " + Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.ToString() + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.ToString() + " " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        });
    }
}
```

Output:

```
start en-US 1
1 de-DE 1
2 de-DE 3
2s de-DE 3
2a en-US 4 4
3 de-DE 4
Finish en-US 1
```

But why is 2a returning en-US and not de-DE? Is it because the executionContext is different? If so, how can I stay in the same execution context?

Comment: Could you link to the documentation you've quoted, please?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn833123(v=vs.110).aspx I have also edited it in the main post

Comment: Was tempted to close this as a typo once I'd worked it out, but I think it's sufficiently interesting to answer instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` are independent properties. You're only setting `CurrentCulture`, and you're reporting that everywhere *except* for 2a, which reports `CurrentUICulture`. If you use the same property consistently throughout the code (either property should be fine), it'll give you the expected results.

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo in my test script. However I am still confused why The System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag changes to my system's default when I pass this line of code:

using (SqlDataReader rdr = await cmd.ExecuteReaderWithRetryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))

Comment: @user1408786: I wonder whether it's a bug in `SqlDataReader`... it may do some messing with the current culture, which is pretty nasty...

Comment: @user1408786: Out of interest, what happens if you don't call `ConfigureAwait(false)`? I wouldn't expect that to make a difference, as the synchronization context isn't the same as the execution context, but it may be related to that...

Comment: In that case it keeps the right culture. So this actually solves my problem. But it means I will need to check all my code

Comment: @user1408786: Ooh, interesting - that's good to know. (When I changed your sample code to use `ConfigureAwait(false)` it made no difference, which is interesting.)